# How do I override or fix this error

Tags: c#, xna

So I want to create a function that creates game objects in my XNA project. I have encountered an error that goes like this and is caused by this code:

**Code:**

```
public void createObject(GameObject gameObject)
{
     string foo;
}
```

**Error:**

```
Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Osiris.GameObject' is less accessible than method 'Osiris.o_functions.createObject(Osiris.GameObject)
```

**EDIT :**

As mentioned below the `GameObject` class wasn't public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `GameObject` class public too:

```
public class GameObject { ... }
```